# For A/B test, how to show the result is significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, ab-test

I have a question: Assuming I have medicine A (new), and medicine B (old). I used two medicine on two groups of patients. After the test, I got two groups of variables, such as
cell damage rate (for A & B), heart beat rate (for A & B), blood sugar (for A & B) ...

How can I say if any of the variables showing significant difference for medicine A and medicine B?  What kind of statistic should I use, t test, or F test, or what else?

Comment: unpaired t test is sufficient, and most common in this scenario

Comment: Were the groups randomised to the treatments or was this an observational study? Also if you have any binary values (e.g., responds/does not respond) then odds ratio is frequently used and tested against null hypothesis that OR=1